# What is an alternate to SQL Triggers in Sql Server Compact Edition?

Tags: wpf, triggers, sql-server-ce

I have moved my WPF application to sql server compact edition(3.5) from sql server express 2008.

Case :(With sql server express 2008)

I have used triggers to update column value.
My Column is comma separated string.
When i was inserting value in database table, another table's column value was being updated using trigger.
Eg.
Table 1:Group
Inserting group name=> "My Personal Group"

(Trigger executes) and then

Table 2:Contact
Column:GroupNames = My Personal Group

Now i want to implement same thing using sql server compact edition(3.5) but it does not support triggers.
I don't know about any alternatives as i am new with sql server compact edition(3.5)

Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds to me like you should do proper database normalization instead

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanx for help i will check database structure..

Answer (score 0):

An approach to working around the lack of triggers is in another stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717689/why-does-sql-server-ce-not-allow-this-trigger-to-fire)